# function set value for another function

Tags: python, function, variables, python-3.x

How can I make the functions

```
def InputName():
    Name = input("Name: ")
def InputCourseName():
    CourseName = input("Course: ")
```

set the Name and CourseName for me to use in:

```
def Criacao(Name, CourseName):
    global Fonte, Output, CorTexto, Raw
    base = Image.open(Raw)
    draw = ImageDraw.Draw(base)        
    draw.text((5,5), Name.upper(), font=Fonte, fill=CorTexto)
    draw.text((6,5), CourseName.upper(), font=Fonte, fill=CorTexto)
```

Would it work if I ran: `Criacao(InputName(), InputCourseName())` ?

Comment: Have you tried your idea? Did it work?

Comment: I added `return Name` and it now works @LevLevitsky

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should start using `return`

```
def InputName():
    name = input("Name: ")
    return name

def InputCourseName():
    courseName = input("Course: ")
    return courseName
```

Then you can use the returned values to assign to local variables

```
def Criacao():
    name = InputName()               # We are using the returned values here
    courseName = InputCourseName()
    global Fonte, Output, CorTexto, Raw
    base = Image.open(Raw)
    draw = ImageDraw.Draw(base)        
    draw.text((5,5), name.upper(), font=Fonte, fill=CorTexto)
    draw.text((6,5), courseName.upper(), font=Fonte, fill=CorTexto)
```

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it would work **if** you return `Name` from your `InputName()` function and `CourseName` from your `InputCourseName()` function.